# How to see last created 3 files in a directory without passing date parameters

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, fedora

How to list the last three new files. it should be sorted on the basis of the lat created status?.

Comment: `ls -1rt|tail -3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following

`$ ls -rt /tmp/ | tail -3`

`ls` will list all the files
 `-r` reverse order while sorting
 `-t` sort by modification time, newest first

`tail` will show you 10 lines by default from last
`-n, --lines=K`
              output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +K to output starting with the Kth